# Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13, why?

Tags: android

I was looking for a solution but found nothing that solved my problem.

```
07-10 13:55:46.943: E/Diag_Lib(13771):  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13
```

Why it can come caused?, How could I fix it?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> error = 13
>   in "errno.h"

```
#define EACCES      13  /* Permission denied */`
```

So, you could see the permission of diag

```
ls -al /dev/diag
```